# Adding array elements to table cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table, cell

```
// Creates a table for my game.
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.border = 1;

// Generates a table with 4 rows and 4 columns
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(row);

    // Creates a cell with the respective number
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        row.appendChild(cell);
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray));
    };
};

innerDiv.appendChild(table);
```

I'm making a memorygame in pure Javascript and this is the code I've come up with to generate the gameboard, a table with 4x4 cells. I have an array of 16 randomly generated numbers (1 paif of each number) and want to place one number in each cell, but I can't manage to wrap my head around how to write the code for it.

Comment: I believe the problem is not incrementing `k` correctly. Try `cell.innerHTML = myArray[i*4+j];` instead of `cell.appendChild(...)`. Of course assuming you have 16 values in `myArray`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[k]));
```

with

```
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i*4+(j+1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the text node to the cell element before you put it into the cell.

```
    // Skapar en cell med respektive siffra.
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[k]));  //// switched line
        row.appendChild(cell);  //// switched line
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

try as follows :

```
// Creates a table for my game.
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.border = 1;

// Generates a table with 4 rows and 4 columns
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(row);

    // Skapar en cell med respektive siffra.
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");      
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[k]));
        row.appendChild(cell);
    };
};

innerDiv.appendChild(table);
```

That you were appending the td before you assign values in it. try appending after creating text node.